How to create a custom message for image(or n-dimensional tensor) in ROS2 Humble?
I am trying to write a custom message in ROS2 Humble which sends images (or any n-dimensional tensor) between nodes and through topics of that custom message type. For the same, I defined a package using this tutorial. These the files and their content:
ros_ws/src/messages_package/msg/image.msg
uint8[][] image

ros_ws/src/messages_package/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(messages)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
# uncomment the following section in order to fill in
# further dependencies manually.
# find_package(<dependency> REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

rosidl_generate_interfaces($(PROJECT_NAME)
"msg/image.msg"
)

ament_package()

ros_ws/src/messages_package/packages.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
    <name>messages</name>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
    <description>TODO: Package description</description>
    <maintainer email="bhavyashah@todo.todo">bhavyashah</maintainer>
    <license>Apache-2.0</license>

    <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

    <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
    <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

    <export>
        <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
    </export>

    <buildtool_depend>rosidl_default_generators</buildtool_depend>
    <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>
    <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>
</package>

I am getting the following error when I build the package using colcon build when I am in ros2_ws folder:
--- stderr: messages                         
CMake Error at /opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_adapter/cmake/rosidl_adapt_interfaces.cmake:59 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/bin/python3 -m rosidl_adapter --package-name messages
  --arguments-file
  /home/bhavyashah/Projects/ros2_ws/build/messages/rosidl_adapter__arguments__$(PROJECT_NAME).json
  --output-dir
  /home/bhavyashah/Projects/ros2_ws/build/messages/rosidl_adapter/messages
  --output-file
  /home/bhavyashah/Projects/ros2_ws/build/messages/rosidl_adapter/$(PROJECT_NAME).idls)
  returned error code 1:

  Error processing 'uint8[][] image' of 'messages/image': ''uint8[]' is an
  invalid message name.  It should have the pattern '^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*$''

  Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_adapter/__main__.py", line 19, in <module>
      sys.exit(main())
    File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_adapter/main.py", line 53, in main
      abs_idl_file = convert_to_idl(
    File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_adapter/__init__.py", line 19, in convert_to_idl
      return convert_msg_to_idl(
    File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_adapter/msg/__init__.py", line 28, in convert_msg_to_idl
      msg = parse_message_string(package_name, input_file.stem, content)
    File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_adapter/parser.py", line 520, in parse_message_string
      Type(type_string, context_package_name=pkg_name),
    File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_adapter/parser.py", line 277, in __init__
      super(Type, self).__init__(
    File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosidl_adapter/parser.py", line 205, in __init__
      raise InvalidResourceName(

  rosidl_adapter.parser.InvalidResourceName: 'uint8[]' is an invalid message
  name.  It should have the pattern '^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*$'

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake:130 (rosidl_adapt_interfaces)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (rosidl_generate_interfaces)


gmake: *** [Makefile:226: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
---
Failed   <<< messages [2.84s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 0 packages finished [3.24s]
  1 package failed: messages
  1 package had stderr output: messages

Thanks in advance for the help.
